# React-select defaultValues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

i have a select menu with defaultValue is null
when i pass props to it , it dosent rerender with the  new props as defaultValues
ps : the select is multi
i tried to use component will recieve props and everything that i find but still dosent work

this is my select component :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import Select from "react-select";

 class SelectMenu extends React.Component {
 state = {
  defaultValues: [],
  };

 componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  this.setState({ defaultValues: newProps.defaultValue });
  }

  render() {
 return (
  <Select
    options={this.props.options}
    closeMenuOnSelect={this.props.closeMenuOnSelect}
    components={this.props.components}
    isMulti={this.props.isMulti}
    onChange={(e) => this.props.onChange(e, this.props.nameOnState)}
    placeholder={this.props.default}
    defaultValue={this.state.defaultValues}
  />
  );
 }  
 }

 export default SelectMenu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the previous solution but its not optimal i find a way to make it work
so instead of defaultvalues
you have to make its as value props
and if you want to catch the deleted and added values to your default
this function will help you alot

```
      onChange = (e) => {
   if (e === null) {
   e = [];
    }
     this.setState({
        equipments: e,
  });
  let added = e.filter((elm) => !this.state.equipments.includes(elm));
  if (added[0]) {
  let data = this.state.deletedEquipments.filter(
    (elm) => elm !== added[0].label
  );
   this.setState({
    deletedEquipments: data,
    });
  }

  let Equipments = e.map((elm) => elm.label);
  let newEquipments = Equipments.filter(
    (elm) => !this.state.fixed.includes(elm)
  );
  this.setState({
   newEquipments: newEquipments,
  });

   let difference = this.state.equipments.filter((elm) => !e.includes(elm));
   if (difference.length !== 0) {
   if (
     !this.state.deletedEquipments.includes(difference[0].label) &&
     this.state.fixed.includes(difference[0].label)
     ) {
     this.setState({
         deletedEquipments: [
         ...this.state.deletedEquipments,
           difference[0].label,
         ],
        });
      }
     }


    };

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    equipments: [],
    newEquipments: [],
   deletedEquipments: [],
  };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillReceiveProps` won't be called during mounting.

> React doesn’t call UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps() with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component’s props may update. (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

Also, `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and will be removed in React 17. Take a look at [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) instead, and especially the notes on when you **do not** need it.

I beleive that in your case using the constructor will be perfectly fine, something like:

```js
class Components extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { some_property: props.defaultValue }
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but its the same the component didnt rerender after the state get changed

Comment: I must have misread you question, my proposed constructor solution won't work indeed. It works works for the initial props do. I would recommend to check `getDerivedStateFromProps`

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution for this problem
by using components will recieve props
and setting my state with the comming props
and in the render you need to do condition to render the select menu only if the state.length !== 0

i posted this answer just in case someone face the same problem i know its not the most optimal solution but it works for me